# Grepping 'nginx -t' for a result

Tags: nginx, bash

Strangely enough this wont work for me.

```
nginx -t | grep -c 'successful' | awk '{if ($0==0) print "not found"; else if ($0>0) print "found"}'
```

It returns a **not found** even though the result is as follows:

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "xxx.co.za" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "xxx.co.za" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
not found
```

Even a simple grep doesn't do whats expected..

```
(nginx -t | grep -q 'successful') && echo "Yes" || echo "Nope"
```

Any idea how I can check if the **nginx -t** command is successful or not?

Comment: The pipe `|` only redirects `stdout` whereas `nginx -t` outputs the information you want to `grep` to `stderr`. To redirect `stderr` through the pipe you would either have to use `|&` or `nginx -t 2>&1 | grep ...`. But the answer of John Mahowald is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the exit value of the nginx command, 0 if success.

```
root@nginx-1-vm:~# nginx -t && printf "Valid\n" || printf "Error\n"
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
Valid
root@nginx-1-vm:~# mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /tmp
root@nginx-1-vm:~# nginx -t && printf "Valid\n" || printf "Error\n"
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Error
```

Better than grep the output, as the messages could be localized or otherwise changed in the future.

Comment: Thanks! Thought as much just didn't go as far as trying to pipe stderr.